# UBUNTU on VMWARE Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, vmware

sorry if my english is horrible: I'm realy stresed :(
I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 that work as virtual machine. Using VMWARE as virtual machine operating system is windows 7.
I'm trying to write a program on linux with C language: that using shared memory. when I try to compile there are no errors but when I execute it I see an error like this:
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
I'm not sure but as far as I learned VMWARE is causing this :S
here are the codes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>    //Process wait
#include <fcntl.h>  //File
//#include <cstdlib>
//#include<fstream.h>

int main(){

  printf("\n Here we go...!");
  int *Numbers;
  Numbers=(int*)getmem(327); // shared memory

  int i,ProcID;
  ProcID=fork(); //depart processor

  if(ProcID==0){          // child processor
    for(i=0;i<50;i++){
      Numbers[i]=random()%50;   
    }
  }else if(ProcID<0){
    printf("\n Hmm... There is an error!");
  }

  int Waiting;
  wait(&Waiting);   

  if(ProcID>0){          // parent processor

    int fileeven,fileodd;
    fileeven=open("EK_even.txt",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0600);
    fileodd=open("EK_odd.txt",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0600);

    for(i=0;i<50;i++){
      if(Numbers[i]%2==0){
    write(fileeven,&Numbers[i],sizeof(Numbers[i]));
      }else{
    write(fileodd,&Numbers[i],sizeof(Numbers[i]));
      }
    }

    close(fileeven);
    close(fileodd);

  }else if(ProcID<0){
    printf("\n Hmm... There is an error!");
  }
  return 1;
}
```

I'm using this to compile on terminal:gcc -o ./RUN ./EK.c -shared
                to Run               :./RUN
                as  result           :Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Thanks for your time and reponds I'm realy in need...

Comment: It would be very very odd for VMware to cause an error like this. Obviously, try the code on a "real" Linux install not running under VMware to confirm. Far more likely is that your code has a bug in it.

Comment: thx for advice i'll try this if works I will let you know...

Comment: It's a bug in the program, it's not the fault of VMWare. You should post your getmem() function. And probably you should check if it fails. Same for the open() calls, they might fail.

Comment: My first action if I don't have any idea (although this one was obvious, as sth pointed out), would be to run my program under Valgrind :) ... hassle-free and easy tracking of bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is VMWare as Marc B said. I tryed it on a real operating system and it worked. getmem() function is not my own function. To use it you have to add "-shared" at the end of compile line. Thanks for replies...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `getmem` takes a number of bytes as a parameter, you allocate 327 bytes for your array of numbers:

```
Numbers=(int*)getmem(327);
```

If you are on a 64 bit system with 8-byte `int`, this is enough space for 40 integers.

You then proceed to put 50 numbers into that array, more than you allocated space for. This might very well cause a segmentation fault.

Generally, start your program in a debugger to see where exactly the segmentation fault occurs. This way you can more easily locate the error in your program.